# Sql, usar un case y poner el resultado en una columna aparte

Tags: sql

Ayuda con lo solicitado, quiero usar un case o if para extraer de una columna llamada nombres solo los 4 primeros digitos y luego compararlo con lo q necesito y si es ok escribirlo al final de la tabla en una columna llamada canal.

así de esta forma seria lo que necesito.

```
select *, case when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'CHT/' then Canal = 'CHAT' when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'BXI/' then Canal = 'HOME BANKING' when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'PTA/' then Canal = 'PORTAL WEB' ELSE Canal = 'LANDING' END AS CANAL from [leads_oct_19]
```

Comment: Hola @Joseph por favor coloca lo que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora y si te esta dando algún error también para poderte ayudar mejor ya que así tu pregunta queda muy abierta. Gracias

Comment: así de esta forma seria lo que necesito.

select *,
case 

 when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'CHT/'
  then Canal = 'CHAT'

 when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'BXI/'
  then Canal = 'HOME BANKING'

 when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'PTA/'
  then Canal = 'PORTAL WEB'

 ELSE Canal = 'LANDING'

END AS CANAL

from [leads_oct_19]

Comment: Edita la pregunta, no añadas código en comentarios.

Comment: @Joseph por favor coloca el resultado que te esta devolviendo y el que tu deseas en tu pregunta no en el comentario. Gracias

Comment: @YoelRodriguez gracias por la ayuda, pero tiene que hacerlo quien pregunto, asi tambien sabemos que esta siguiendo su pregunta. Ademas tiene que agregar el resultado esperado.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion ahi

Comment: @jasilva Lo se.. pero en este momento, es como una pregunta abandonada.. Asi que entiendo que se tomen el tiempo en tratar de mejorar la pregunta, pero es algo que el propio usuario que pregunto puede hacer. Asi como esta, por mas que se agregue eso, le falta informacion que tiene que agregar el usuario. No tiene sentido agregar eso si el usuario no sigue su propia pregunta. Por eso se le pide al usuario que lo haga y que agregue lo que falta.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta está casi bien, pero tienes un error conceptual. No tienes por qué asignar un valor para obtener el campo

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
  when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'CHT/' then 'CHAT' 
  when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'BXI/' then 'HOME BANKING' 
  when SUBSTRING(Nombres,1,4) = 'PTA/' then 'PORTAL WEB' 
  ELSE 'LANDING' 
END AS CANAL from [leads_oct_19]
```